# Using formula.js on vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, formula.js

I am trying to use formulja.js in a Vue project. When I import it and try to use PPMT function I am getting this error. I can't define what the error is and how to solve it.  Please can someone help

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                           5:23:41 PM

 error  in ./node_modules/@formulajs/formulajs/lib/esm/index.mjs

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1453:25)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   }
| 
>   delimiter = delimiter ?? '';
| 
|   let flatArgs = flatten(args);

 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Table.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 59:0-45 74:24-33
 @ ./src/components/Table.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/components/Table.vue
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/components/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/components/Home.vue
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.178.69:8081&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

How I am using it

```
<script>
import formulajs from "@formulajs/formulajs"
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      rate: 0,
      pv: 0,
      nper: 0,
    };
  },
computed:{
 totalPPMT() {
     let per = 1;
     let ppmt = 0
     while(this.nper >= 0){
         let calc_ppmt = formulajs.PPMT(this.rate,per,this.nper,this.pv,0,0)
         per++
         ppmt += calc_ppmt
     }
      return ppmt;
    },
},
<script/>
```

Comment: It looks like webpack doesn't understand `??` being used inside the `formulajs` package.

Comment: Yes, I used ternary operation instead of ?? to check if it is null or undefined. Thank you

Comment: The error message _"You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders"_ seems to ask that you look there for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem：
Convert the formulajs package in node_modules to babel through vue.config.js：

```
  module.exports = {
    transpileDependencies: ['@formulajs/formulajs']
  }
```